# How to transform a nested case class to another nested case which has one extra field inside the nested class using chimney in scala

Tags: scala, generics, dto, shapeless, hlist

```
package a

final case class mySettings(multicache: myCacheSetting, defaultTtlHours: Duration)

final case class myCacheSetting(
    weightedRoundrobin: InternalWRRMultiCacheSetting,
    attempts: Int,
    clusters: Seq[MyClusterSetting]
)

final case class MyClusterSetting(id: String, settings: InternalMyClientSettings)

final case class InternalMyClientSettings(
    user: String,
    environment: Option[InternalMyClientEnvironmentSettings]
)

final case class InternalMyClientEnvironmentSettings(
    socketTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration],
    connectTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration],
)
final case class InternalWRRMultiCacheSetting(maxWeight: Int, incrementWeight: Int, decrementWeight: Int)
```

This class needs to be converted into

```
package b

final case class mySettings(multicache: myCacheSetting, defaultTtlHours: Duration)

final case class myCacheSetting(
    weightedRoundrobin: InternalWRRMultiCacheSetting,
    attempts: Int,
    clusters: Seq[MyClusterSetting]
)

final case class MyClusterSetting(id: String, settings: InternalMyClientSettings)

final case class InternalMyClientSettings(
    user: String,
    company: String,
    environment: Option[InternalMyClientEnvironmentSettings]
)

final case class InternalMyClientEnvironmentSettings(
    socketTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration],
    connectTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration],
)
final case class InternalWRRMultiCacheSetting(maxWeight: Int, incrementWeight: Int, decrementWeight: Int)
```

as you can see both classes are almost similar except that the second class contains an additional field `company`. `company` needs to be filled with a constant.

A explaination on how you found the solution will be appreciated

I tried using into and transformInfo from scalaland:chimney but it didnt help.
The missing field is causing a lot of issues while transforming

Comment: *"I tried using into and transformInfo from scalaland:chimney but it didnt help"* What does this mean specifically? Please provide details what you tried and what errors you got.

Comment: You're writing about Chimney but you tagged your question with `shapeless`. What solution are interested in, Chimney or Shapeless?

Comment: Migration of case classes is a standard task for Chimney https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/ and Shapeless https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:ops:migration (6.3).

Comment: @dmytro I am intrested in chimney or shapeless both. Chimney is easy to understand. and tag for chimney was not present.
I tried but everything led to the error of company field missing

Comment: I was looking for old questions with Chimney and with this one I found out that it can be made to compile with one implicit - see Scastie https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4bNoIhu6Rge3XS0HASXKjA - 0.8.2 added ability to set field in nested path, but here it requires setting each value in a collection, so implicit would be better.